# Bubble sort double linked list

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, bubble-sort

Hello everyone I'm trying to sort my double linked list in C using bubble sort algorithm. Here is my code:

```
struct node {
                unsigned char key;
                unsigned char num;
                struct node *left;
                struct node *right;
            };
```

Here is my sort funcion:

```
void sort(int count, struct node *t_node)
{
    struct node *tmp,*nextnode, *node1, *node2;

    for(node1 = t_node;node1->right != NULL ;node1 = node1->right) {
        for(node2 = node1->right; node2->right != NULL; node2 = node2->right) {
            if(node2->key > node2->right->key)
            {               
                nextnode = node2->right;
                tmp = node2->left;
                node2->right = nextnode->right;             
                node2->left = nextnode->left;
                nextnode->right = node2;
                nextnode->left = tmp;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It works in 80% because for example data:

```
node1 key=3
node2 key=144
node3 key=49
node4 key=207
```

The result after sort is:

```
node1 key=3
node2 key=144
node4 key=207
```

Why my third node disappeared? Where is the problem?

Comment: What about `tmp->right` and `nextnode->right->left`?

Comment: How should they be assigned?

Comment: Consider abstracting the swap to a separate function. Make sure the edge cases (swapping to and away from the start or end of the list) work.

Comment: Consider allocating a temporary array, copying the values from the list there, sorting the array using a simple `qsort()`, and then copying back into the list. No list changes needed, this is often way simpler and easier to get right. It does pay with higher (temporary) memory usage, of course.

Comment: @unwind ..and typically faster :)

Comment: @unwind I think OP have done that as an exercice of manipulation on double-linked list, even though you are correct I don't think OP's code is anything made to be "really used"

Comment: @Eregrith - I sincerely hope not:)

Comment: Even when all the bugs are out, it will be slower than Ruby.

Comment: I'm tempted to closevote this as an attempt to outsource debugging on a complex and essentially flawed data design that no professional/enthusiast developer would ever use:(

Comment: @Zobo Why did you ask the same question anew about the bubble_sort for a double-linked list if you already asked this question here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a double-linked list. To swap two nodes, typically 6 pointers need to be updated. Say we have `A <-> B <-> C <-> D` and you want to swap `B` and `C`: you'll need to update `right` of `A`, `B`, and `C`, and also `left` of `B`, `C`, and `D`.

Your code is only updating 4 pointers here:

```
        if(node2->key > node2->right->key)
        {               
            nextnode = node2->right;
            tmp = node2->left;
            node2->right = nextnode->right;             
            node2->left = nextnode->left;
            nextnode->right = node2;
            nextnode->left = tmp;
        }
```

This shall fix your issue:

```
        if(node2->key > node2->right->key)
        {               
            nextnode = node2->right;
            tmp = node2->left;
            if (tmp)
                tmp->right = nextnode;
            if (nextnode->right)
                nextnode->right->left = node2;
            node2->right = nextnode->right;             
            node2->left = nextnode->left;
            nextnode->right = node2;
            nextnode->left = tmp;
        }
```

Comment: I have problem when sorting example data: 
Before sort:
 `Node value: 199
 Node value: 100
 Node value: 12
 Node value: 101`
After sort I got:
`Node value: 199
 Node value: 12
 Node value: 101`
Where is the bug?

Answer (score 1):

You also need to replace the previous node (`tmp` in your code but I'd suggest a more explicit name...) `right` pointer, and the next-next node's left pointer :

```
tmp <-> node1 <-> node2 <-> nextnext
```

You are on `node1` and detect you need to swap it with `node2` :

- You need to have `tmp` -> `node1`  changed to `tmp` -> `node2`
- You need to have `node2` <- `nextnext` changed to `node1` <- `nextnext` as well